# How to display the value instead of percentage in a pie chart using jquery Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

for a project of mine im using a pie char that made with jQuery Highcharts. what like to do is to display the value i inserted instead of the the parentage. example: chart shows firefox - 43.269...% instead i like to show the value Firefox -45 clicks. can anyone help me with this. thanks in advance.

Chart code

```
<!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>

    <!-- 1a) Optional: add a theme file -->
    <!--
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/themes/gray.js"></script>
    -->

    <!-- 1b) Optional: the exporting module -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>


    <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'browser_cart',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' clicks';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: [
                        ['Firefox',   45],
                        ['IE',       26],
                        ['Chrome',   12], 
                        ['Safari',    8],
                        ['Opera',     6],
                        ['Others',   7]
                    ]
                }]
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- 3. Add the container -->
    <div id="browser_cart" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: **Tooltip options** > - [Highcharts Options Reference for Tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) **Example:** > - [highcharts demo](http://highcharts.com/demo/?example=combo&theme=default) **Source:** > - [highslide.com/forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7302)

Answer (score 52):

Fixed, Just Changed below line

```
  format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
```

to

```
  format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y:.1f} Rs.',
```

Comment: And if I want to use an int type for the number? I mean, this is works, but with 250.0, 77.0, etc. I want to 77, 250. Any help?

Comment: you could try  this `format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y:.0f} Rs.'`, instead.

Comment: This was worked for me  pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>'

Answer (score 26):

```
return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' clicks';
```

Answer (score 14):

In this case you can replace "this.percentage" to "this.point.y"

Look at formatter: (old link removed), new link - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Checking again, I may have wrongly downvoted. The link is working. I apologized for this. Upvoting again.